# Jquery: How to click link when click any anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have this code:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Open in new tab </a>
```

When I click anywhere in website, the above link will be clicked. So, the new tab will be opened. How to do that ? I searched and tried a lot but failed.

Comment: i think that sounds like not honest behavior of site. link thats insensibly opens in background - it's bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does not sound like great user experience, but here goes anyway:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function(){
     window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It triggers the `click` handlers. It won't open any window.

Comment: You have to write direct `winodw.open()` because it `triggers` the click handlers.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. I copy your code and it doesn't work when I click